# Minimal error given when making an approximation of $f(x)$ by sines and cosines

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, approximation, harmonic-analysis

I am studying by myself Fourier analysis and have encountered the following problem:

We are trying to approximate a function by a finite sum of sines and cosines with general constant coeficients:

$$f(x) \cong \Sigma_{k=0}^N (A_kcos(kx)) + B_ksin(kx)$$

Define the square approximated error by:

$$E = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f(x)-\Sigma_{k=0}^{N}(A_kcos(kx)+B_ksin(kx))]^2dx$$

Prove that the minimal error is given when we choose $A_k$ as the Fourier coefficient $a_k$ and $B_k$ as the Fourier coefficient $b_k$.

I tried proving this by induction on $N$ but only $N=0$ worked..
I would like to find a minimum point by differentiating but I am not sure how to do that here..

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get in general if $v_1,…,v_N$ is an orthogonal set of vectors, that the minimum of 
$$
\Bigl\|u-\sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k\Bigr\|^2=\|u\|^2-2\sum_{k=1}^N c_k\langle u,v_k\rangle+\sum_{k=1}^N c_k^2\|v_k\|^2
$$
is attained at the Fourier coefficients
$$
c_k=\frac{\langle u,v_k\rangle}{\|v_k\|^2}
$$
which you can either prove via the zeros of the gradient or by completing the squares.
$$
\Bigl\|u-\sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k\Bigr\|^2=\|u\|^2-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{\langle u,v_k\rangle^2}{\|v_k\|^2}+\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1{\|v_k\|^2}\Bigl(c_k\|v_k\|^2-\langle u,v_k\rangle\Bigr)^2
$$

Comment: Was very helpfull. Thank you!!